# .htaccess : How to prohibit access to a directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, structure, directory

Here is the folder structure for my current PHP project :

```
root
   |_classes
   |_ctrl
   |_pages
   |_webroot
     |_index.php
   |_config.php
```

**Here is my problem :**

`/webroot/index.php` is the webroot. The index.php file includes every page requested by the user. These pages are stored in `/pages`. So I need my site to have access to the folders that are located higher in the folder structure.

But I also don't want the users to have access to all the other files and folders (`config.php`, `classes/`, ...).

So, in other words, my site looks like this : `www.mysite.com/webroot/index.php`. I do not want the users to go to `www.mysite.com/config.php`, or `www.mysite.com/classes/...`, etc.

Oh yeah, and of course, I don't want the user's browser to display the webroot folder in the url, so is it possible to rewrite the url to make it look nicer ?

How can I do something like that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have found the solution. I have added these directives into my `.conf` file : `ServerRoot` and `DocumentRoot`.

- `ServerRoot` is the root of the server. Users don't necessarily have access to the root.
- `DocumentRoot` is the path from where from which users can access.

I hope this helps.